# Rails 4: Helper method not retrieving associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, helper

I have a custom helper method who's sole purpose is to count data of associated records which will be displayed in the view. In the rails console I can add `Campaign.find(1).plan.subscribers` and retrieve the list of subscribers yet, I can't do that in my custom Helper Method.

Here's the helper method.. *(Note: You can see where I tried printing out `campaign.plan.subscribers` to see if it was registering before the loop...it's not)*

**helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper

    def current_recipients(campaign)
        @target_program = campaign.program.name
        @recipients = 0

        #p campaign.plan.subscribers

        campaign.plan.subscribers.each do |s|
            case @target_program
                when "Caspian Star" && s.star?
                    @recipients += 1
                when "STIX" && s.stix?
                    @recipients += 1
                when "PPCI" && s.ppci?
                    @recipients += 1
                else
                    @recipients += 0
                end
        end
        @recipients
    end
end
```

My spec..

**spec/helpers.application_helper_spec.rb**

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe ApplicationHelper, :type => :helper do

    describe "Counting campaign recipients" do
        subject(:campaign) { create(:campaign, plan: plan, program: program) }
        let(:program) { create(:program) }
        let(:plan) { create(:plan) }

        it "finds subscribers under campaign plan and program" do
            expect(helper.current_recipients(campaign)).to eq 3
        end
    end
end
```

**Failure**

```
  1) ApplicationHelper Counting campaign recipients finds subscribers under campaign plan and program
     Failure/Error: expect(helper.current_recipients(campaign)).to eq 3

       expected: 3
            got: 0

       (compared using ==)
```

The relationships..

**app/models/..**

```
Class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :program
    belongs_to :plan
end

Class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :campaigns
    has_many :subscribers, through: :plannables
    has_many :plannables
end

Class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :campaigns
end

class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :plans, through: :plannables
    has_many :plannables
end

class Plannable < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :plan
    belongs_to :provider
end
```

**EDIT**

Here's the add factories as requested.

```
FactoryGirl.define do

    factory :campaign do |x|
        x.sequence(:name) { |y| "Q6 201#{y}" }
        x.sequence(:comment) { |y| "JIRA OI-6#{y}" }
        channels ["Folder", "Fax"]
    end

    factory :program do
        name "Caspian Star"
    end

    factory :plan do
        name "Third Storm Connect"
    end
end
```

Comment: When you create the test campaign, how are you linking the program and subscribers?  Unless you have factory magic you aren't showing us, it doesn't look like that is happening.

Comment: @steveklein - A subscriber has a boolean field for each program opt-in/out status, so the `case` statement matches the name of the program with each subscriber's boolean field and if the boolean field is true, then the recipient count += 1.

Comment: No I am asking about your test setup.  Where are you linking the campaign you are creating to a program and that program to subscribers?  Maybe you can show your factory in your OP.

Comment: Thx - I see the factories.  Where are you defining the program or plan for the test campaign?  In your subject line, how are "program" and "plan" getting initialized?

Comment: @steveklein - I updated the post with the factory file. As far as testing goes, I'm not too sure how that's done so I added seed data to the test database for subscribers and named the plan based off an existing plan. Instead of `let(:plan) { create(:plan) }` I tried `let(:plan) { Plan.find(2) }` in order to grab an existing plan but received an error. I'm very new and still wrapping my head around TDD and Factory Girl in general.

Comment: @steveklein - My understanding is that they are initialized when I call the `campaign` variable when the spec triggers it via `expect(helper.current_recipients(campaign)).to eq 3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80814/discussion-between-steve-klein-and-shroy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being in the `case` statement which wasn't throwing any obvious errors. It didn't respond well to the `&&` on the `when` conditions, so I placed them underneath and it seems to work fine now. Here is what the code looks like now..

```
module ApplicationHelper

    def current_recipients(campaign)
        @target_program = campaign.program.name
        @recipients = 0

        campaign.plan.subscribers.each do |s|
            case @target_program
                when "Caspian Star"
                    s.star?
                    @recipients += 1
                when "STIX"
                    s.stix?
                    @recipients += 1
                when "PPCI"
                    s.ppci?
                    @recipients += 1
                else
                    @recipients += 0
                end
        end
        @recipients
    end
end
```

With a suggestion made by @steveklein during a chat session, I was able to get my test to pass by linking my objects associations together in this manner..

```
describe "Counting campaign recipients" do
    it "finds subscribers under chosen campaign plan and program" do
        campaign = create(:campaign)
        plan = create(:plan)
        campaign.plan = plan
        campaign.program = create(:program)

    3.times do
        subscriber = create(:subscriber, star: true)
        subscriber.plans << plan
    end

        expect(helper.current_recipients(campaign)).to eq 3
    end
end
```